# How to create a simple Tile/ Card in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to find a sample solution for how to create a simple square/ rectangle tile, with a count or sum value in the center - a KPI tile. THis kind of tile is common in PowerBI or other tools and it's probably so simple that HighCharts themselves don't even have an example on their demo site. If anyone has a jsfiddle of how to create one that would wonderful. thanks

Here's a link to the equivilent in powerBI
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-card?tabs=powerbi-desktop

I haven't tried anything as I couldn't find a sample to work from, which is my approach generally with Highcharts.

Comment: Why do you need Highcharts for this?

Comment: I was thinking only that it gives consistency around how the dashboard is configured, and how we interact with those components. What would you suggest otherwise please?

Answer (score 0):

To create a simple shape, that could be a tile you can render it by [Highcharts.SVGRenderer](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer), inside you can show for example point value.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    data: [29.9]
  }],
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  }

}, function(chart) {

  var point = chart.series[0].data[0],
    text = chart.renderer.text(
      `${point.y}`,
      point.plotX + chart.plotLeft + 10,
      point.plotY + chart.plotTop - 10
    ).attr({
      zIndex: 5
    }).add(),
    box = text.getBBox();

  console.log(point)

  chart.renderer.rect(box.x - 50, box.y - 50, box.width + 100, box.height + 100, 5)
    .attr({
      fill: '#FFFFEF',
      stroke: 'gray',
      'stroke-width': 1,
      zIndex: 4
    })
    .add();
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hsefvL7b/